# Forground service notification get replaced by another notification

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

I have two forground service FS1 and FS2 , with each one i create notification , if FS1 is running and i start FS2 the old notification get replaced , i want both to stay ,
this is how i create notification

```
    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val notificationChannelId = "123"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                "Notification service channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).let {
                it.description = "Notification Service channel"
                it.enableLights(true)
                it.lightColor = Color.RED
                it.enableVibration(true)
                it.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
                it
            }

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)


        }

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
        }

        val builder: Notification.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) Notification.Builder(
            this,
            notificationChannelId
        ) else Notification.Builder(this)


        return builder

            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("Content")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setTicker("Ticker text")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH) 
            .build()

    }
```

and in the onCreate methode

```
 val notification = createNotification()
        startForeground(1, notification)
```

and in the other service i create notification with the same way !

Comment: Use different notificationChannelId for each notification

Comment: I am already using different id

Comment: anyway Thanks zain , i was using the same id at the startForeground methode in both services

Answer (score 0):

Ok  my bad , i found out why , at onCreate methode , in both services i was using id 1 , i should use different id